# Woocommerce Products don't update

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I try to update my products in Woocommerce. Woocommerce say's "it's done", but after i view the products nothing happend.

**side notes:**

- somethimes when i do an upload, it changed some of the products (titles, short discription, discription).

Is it because of a 12/24 timefrime, that you can't update that much? Or is there something else going on.

Comment: disable all plugins except woocommerce. Change theme to storefront and test again. enable debug logs and share what u get there.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to enable wp_debug (docs here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and see if something bad is happening.
The other thing i can think of is some kind of cache plugin or cache on server side which is malconfigured

Comment: This isn't a great answer, to a not so great question.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, to solve problems, one should start with the simplest methods and work towards more difficult solutions.

Usually, if you cannot update your products, it may be due to information being stored in the cookie section and browser sessions, causing interference. First, it is best to clear these values.

Next, you need to activate the WordPress debug section by following these steps:

After entering the WordPress installation path in public_html, you should search for the wp-config.php file in this directory. Once you have found the file, right-click on it and select "Edit" to open the file editing page. Search for the term "WP_DEBUG" within the code by using the keyboard shortcut CTRL + F.

If no results are found when searching for the term "WP_DEBUG", it means that there is no code related to enabling debugging in WordPress, and you will need to add this code manually. To do this, add the following code just before the line /* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */ and save the file.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

Once you have completed these steps, you can safely solve your problem. If you are unable to identify the issue, it is better to post the errors you received here so we can provide better guidance.